# Debugging with command line arguments in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I might be blind, but I can't for the life of me find out where to set command line arguments for debugging in Visual Studio 2015.

In VS 2013 (and every other version I've used) you can [add them in the Debugging section of a project properties page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1ktzfy9w(v=vs.100).aspx)). Is there any way I can set them via the IDE in VS 2015?

Comment: It still works the exact same way.  A missing property page is usually caused by a corrupt install.  Which in turn is usually caused by having a beta version installed on the machine that wasn't properly uninstalled.  Spin the wheel of fortune by uninstalling with the /uninstall /force command line options, then install again.

Comment: What type of project are you seeing this in? Universal App?

Answer (score 6):

For .Net builds, open project properties and select the Debug tab. Command line args can be added under the 'Start Options' section.
For native builds, open project properties and select the Debugging tab under Configuration Properties. Command line args can be added (for the local debugger) in the 'Command Arguments' field.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Project (not the Solution!) in Solution Explorer and select Properties >>> Debug >>> Start Options >>> Command line arguments